# How can i change date like given description in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dataset

here in Days section '2020-april-4'  i want to change it like this 4-04-2020 that's mean date/month/year. how can i do it?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could simply use a `datetime` module to do that.

Your current format is `%Y-%B-%d`

Your desired format is `%-d-%m-%Y`

Here is an example for a single variable:

```
from datetime import datetime


mydate = '2020-April-04'

# Convert "mydate" string to a datetime object
converted_mydate = datetime.strptime(mydate, '%Y-%B-%d')

# This will print a datetime object
print(converted_mydate)

>>> 2020-04-04 00:00:00

# Change formatting to your desired style (and convert it to a string)
changed_mydate = converted_mydate.strftime('%-d-%m-%Y')

# This will print a string of your desired formatted datetime
print(changed_mydate)

>>> 4-04-2020
```

You can make it a function and apply to your "Day" column in a DataFrame with `df.apply` like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


def chg_format(date_in):
    date_out = datetime.strptime(mydate, '%Y-%B-%d')
    date_out = date_out.strftime('%-d-%m-%Y')

    return date_out


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'Day': ['2020-April-04', '2020-June-09', '2021-May-23']
})

df['Day'] = df['Day'].apply(chg_format)
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope below lines should be helpful to change the date format in padas.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%B-%d')  #string to date if required
df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')     # this line will directly work if format is date time
```

here is snap

[image]